# std::bind fails to compile with std::atomic_bool& on MSVC

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind, stdatomic

I'm using VC++ to compile my program (using Visual Studio 2015, update 3) and some snippet fails to compile.

basically, I want to bind a function which gets a reference to atomic boolean with atomic boolean. self containing code:

```
void stub(std::atomic_bool& b) {
    b = true;
}

int main() {
    std::atomic_bool b(false);
    std::function<void()> delegate = std::bind(stub, b); //fails to compile

    auto& ref = b;
    std::function<void()> delegate0 = std::bind(stub, ref); //fails to compile

    std::function<void()> delegate1 = std::bind(stub, std::ref(b)); //compiled
/*...*/
    }
```

the compiler stack trace:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(357): error C2665: 'std::tuple<std::atomic<bool>>::tuple': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\tuple(608): note: could be 'std::tuple<std::atomic<bool>>::tuple(std::tuple<std::atomic<bool>> &&)'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\tuple(607): note: or       'std::tuple<std::atomic<bool>>::tuple(const std::tuple<std::atomic<bool>> &)'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(357): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::atomic<bool>)'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(866): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Compressed_pair<void (__cdecl *)(std::atomic_bool &),std::tuple<std::atomic<bool>>,false>::_Compressed_pair<void(__cdecl &)(std::atomic_bool &),_Cv_TiD&>(std::_One_then_variadic_args_t,_Other1,_Cv_TiD &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Cv_TiD=std::atomic<bool>,
1>              _Other1=void (__cdecl &)(std::atomic_bool &)
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(864): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Compressed_pair<void (__cdecl *)(std::atomic_bool &),std::tuple<std::atomic<bool>>,false>::_Compressed_pair<void(__cdecl &)(std::atomic_bool &),_Cv_TiD&>(std::_One_then_variadic_args_t,_Other1,_Cv_TiD &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Cv_TiD=std::atomic<bool>,
1>              _Other1=void (__cdecl &)(std::atomic_bool &)
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(863): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl &)(std::atomic_bool &),std::atomic_bool &>::_Binder(_Fx,std::atomic_bool &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fx=void (__cdecl &)(std::atomic_bool &)
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(890): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl &)(std::atomic_bool &),std::atomic_bool &>::_Binder(_Fx,std::atomic_bool &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fx=void (__cdecl &)(std::atomic_bool &)
1>          ]
1>  c:\visual studio 2015\projects\quantum\quantum\main.cpp(658): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl &)(std::atomic_bool &),std::atomic_bool &>' being compiled
```

Is there something I miss or it's the compiler fault?

Comment: Atomics aren't copyable. That's why you need `std::ref`.

Comment: @KerrekSB why is the program trying to copy an atomic? the function gets a reference as parameter, the atomic is passed as reference, can't see what is being copied here beside a reference

Comment: It seems that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the C++ type and object model. You *never* "copy references". You always *copy values*. Values are never references. References are a kind of *variable* that you can use to designate values. So when you say `ref`, that's a value of type `std::atomic_bool` (and it happens to be the same value as `b`). When you say `std::ref(b)` (or `std::ref(ref)`), that's  a value of type `std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic_bool>`, and `std::bind` has a protocol for interpreting that.

Comment: `std::bind` always copies or moves its input arguments, as it has to return a bound function object that includes the original arguments. std::ref works by returning a copyable object that can be converted back to a reference at a later time.

Comment: @DaveS: You cannot "convert to a reference", since you can only convert *values*, and values are never references.

Comment: @KerrekSB yet, if I create a class with a reference to atomic_bool, I can use the copy constructor, so I don't get the "copy values" part. std::bind should Imitate that kind of class + `operator()`.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  In this case, I was reffering to the `operator T&` conversion operator on the `std::reference_wrapper<T>` class.  I was being unclear, and my comment was are response to the comment before yours

Comment: @DaveS: Yeah, I get that :-) Most of the time, it's OK to be sloppy and say things like "return a reference", and it's clear from the context what you meant (namely "return an lvalue"). This is one of the rare questions where the sloppiness actually causes genuine confusion, so it's important to be precise here.

Comment: @DavidHaim: "*I can use the copy constructor*" Copy constructor of what? If you're talking about the copy constructor of the outer type, you're simply creating a reference to the same object as the other object's member. Which, btw, breaks the concept of value types.

Comment: @DavidHaim: A copy constructor doesn't copy values. It specifies how to *initialize* an object from an existing object of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind` always tries to store *values* of the parameters, never references. `atomic` types cannot be copied. So when `bind` tries to copy them, it will fail.

This is one of the reasons `reference_wrapper` exists: to allow a reference to an object to be used in a place where a value is expected. Indeed, `std::ref` was invented primarily to deal with `bind`.

See, `bind` could have stored references to parameters. However, storing references can be very dangerous, especially references to stack variables which may stop existing sometime before the `bind` functor gets called. So `bind` forces you to be *explicit* about when you store references; it makes you use `ref`.

Comment: @DavidHaim: References are not objects. `bind` will always store values; whether it copies or moves them depends on what you pass to the function. But it will store values, not references.

Comment: @Nicole Bolas, I don't necessarily agree with your logic. c++ is unsafe language. you can still return a pointer or a reference to local variable from a function. you can store a dangling pointer inside the bound expression. disabling reference for that cost is meaningless.

Comment: @DavidHaim: "*I don't necessarily agree with your logic.*" Agree or disagree all you want, but that's why Boost (and the standard library version) did it this way. I'm just relating their position on the matter. And just because a language is not safe does not mean you should go around creating *more* unsafe things. C++ after all requires you to use `&` or `*` when returning such things, so at least you can tell when something is potentially unsafe. By default, C++ passes/returns values.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Equally importantly, if `bind` stored references by default, how would you say that you want to store a *value*?

Comment: no doubt that this is how `std::bind` is implemented and my opinion will not magically change that, I just think that this is counter intuitive.

Comment: an ideal implementation of `std::bind` would look at the parameters types the callable expects to get and store the parameters accordingly.

Comment: @DavidHaim: So if I have a function that takes a `const&` parameter, but I want the `bind` expression to take a value... how do I do that? The decision about whether the `bind`er stores a value or a reference is *not* based on the parameters of the bound function. It's based on what you want to do with that `bind`er. If you want to store that binder long-term, it *needs* to store values. If you're using it locally, then you can get away with references to stack variables. That has *nothing* to do with what parameters the function takes.

Comment: @DavidHaim Besides what Nicol said, what do you want `struct C { void operator()(const int&, double) const; void operator()(int, int) const; }; int x = 0; std::bind(C(), x, std::placeholders::_1);` to store?

Answer (score 1):

`std::atomic` types are not CopyConstructible. Your (erroring) invocations to `std::bind()` would create copies.

Additionally, you appear to misunderstand how references work - `auto& ref = b` does of course create a reference to `b`; but `ref` is still an lvalue in its own right and as such, passing it to `std::bind()` does not suddenly change the behaviour.

Finally, considering you're using atomics, which is C++11, this means you also have access to lambdas which would allow you to express your code without having to resort to `std::ref`:

```
std::function<void()> delegate = [&b] { b = true; };
```

Beware however! In either case, whether you use `std::bind` + `std::ref` or my lambda example above, you **must** ensure that `b` remains valid until you are done with `delegate` - taking a reference *does not* extend the original object's lifetime.